# How to validate a SKOS file?

Tags: api, validation

At the first ,I have to say,my English is so so .
 Now I need something to check my skos file whether it is valid.Is there some API or some tools can do so?
 I know there are one web service can do so,but I have to develop a system,so what I need most is a API .
 validating Skos files ,I mean,it can find the errors in skos types and propeties,such as the skos:broad (the valid one is skos:broader) .
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of hints are given here : [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/417/validate-against-rdf-vocabulary](https://web.archive.org/web/20140916181941/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/417/validate-against-rdf-vocabulary). However, there are no direct, open-source api that you can integrate in your project, to my knowledge.
Also have a look [here](http://www.proxml.be/users/paul/weblog/40127/SPARQL_for_SKOS_integrity_constraints.html) and [here](http://www.proxml.be/users/paul/weblog/d1855/Where_OWL_fails_another_OWL_arises.html), if you have a triple Store with SPARQL support.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks very much.Now I parse the SKOS with SAX,just like parse xml,and I programed to get the tags of SKOS,and then to compare it with the one valided,if not ,then throw out an exception and stop,I don't know whether it is the right way to do so!

Comment: Well, that's a first step. But it's not enough... This approach won't find problem like a skos:related relation to a skos:broader term, I think...